# Type of undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is not a practical problem, I just need an explanation.

I have the following code:

```
var src = container.find('img').attr('src');
if(src === 'undefined') {
    alert('No src');
}
```

When i fire up the console and log the src it says it's undefined but the alert is not fired. Debugging this piece of code justifies previous behaviour. When i remove the '' in the if statement and leave undefined as a type, the alert gets triggered.

On the other hand, further down my code i have this piece:

```
var pathname = (window.location.pathname).split('/');
if(pathname[5] === 'undefined') {
    alert('Something...');
}
```

And the alert gets triggered properly whenever the console says that pathname[5] is undefined.

Therefore, i figured that in the first case undefined is returned as type and in the second as a string. Is this correct, and why such behaviour?

Thanks for all smart answers!

Comment: `"undefined" !== undefined`

Comment: Just if (typeof src === 'undefined') and it'll be done

Comment: undefined is a type not a value...=== compares value and types and !== says it's not equal in value or type..don't be confused with the values...you should focus on the operators...== compares values === compares both values and types

Comment: What browser did you use? I tried your `split()` example in latest Firefox, Chrome and IE9 and in all cases `pathname[5] === 'undefined'` returned false.

Comment: I am using chrome canary for development, but also tried regular last version of chrome and safari...

Comment: @AlvinArulselvan I agree on the comparison, but if the returned undefined is always of type undefined and not string, how come the comparison in the second example passes as true? Do you get my point here?

Comment: Check what console.log(typeof pathname[5]); and console.log(typeof src); gives you, my gut feel is that this is related to the great Identity vs Equality feature of js =) http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2009/11/javascripts-evil-equality-twins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know `===` operator It not only check the value but also datatype of variable.

So in first case it is not getting true as in javascript `undefined` is not a string.

So try:

```
if(src === undefined) {
    alert('No src');
}
```

In second case it is still returning false. [Here is JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BR7XU/)

try this:

```
var loc="/~svemirko/dreamhouse/admin/homepage/";
var pathname = (loc).split('/');

if(pathname[7] === undefined) {
    alert('Something...');
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know that and i choose to use strict comparison by default and continuing the practice in this case also. Im just curious why in the first example undefined is returned as a type and in the second as a string (if thats the case here).

Comment: Yes you are correct here, but why such behaviour?!?!? Is it just me considering this crazy?

Comment: "/~svemirko/dreamhouse/admin/homepage/"

Comment: check the demo... condition is false in second case too

Comment: This started giving me headache. I'll use the approach you proposed here and accept your answer. Thank you and everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

Since `src` has already has been declared all you need to do is check its truthyness:

```
if (!src) alert('no src');
```

If the variable can have a falsy value (empty string, zero, false) then you should check for both `undefined` and `null` like:

```
if (src === null || src === undefined)
```

Or taking advantage of type casting since `null == undefined`

```
if (src == null)
```

Comment: In the end i used the first approach you proposed (if(!src)), but still I want to know why is the undefined returned as type in the first case and as a string in the other, if i am correct there?
Thanks!

Comment: @Svemirko: `undefined` is a predefined variable with a value of type `"undefined"`. That's the confusion.

Comment: I understand that, but dont you agree that in that case returned undefined, with the value of type undefined should fail the strict comparison in the second example (undefined === 'undefined')?

Comment: It should fail http://jsbin.com/iwavan/1/edit. My guess is that `"undefined"` must be already a string in your pathname. Somewhere else in the code you missed an `undefined` check and it's propagating...

Comment: That is correct, it is a string, but why?!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
var src = container.find('img').attr('src');
if(typeof(src) === 'undefined') {
    alert('No src');
}
```